# Without complement solve combinatorics problem

Tags: combinatorics

For the question

> A Math Club consists of $16$ males and $15$ females. How many ways can the club elect a president, vice president, and treasurer if at least one officer must be female?

The way I tried to do this problem is that there are three cases:

- i) If one officer is female: $15 \cdot {_{16}P_2}$
- ii) If two officers are female: ${_{15}P_2} \cdot {_{16}P_1}$
- iii) If three officers are female: ${_{15}P_3}$

Then I add the three cases $15 \cdot {_{16}P_2} + {_{15}P_2} \cdot {_{16}P_1} + {_{15}P_3} = 9,690$ but the answer is wrong because when I use the complement I get ${_{31}P_3} - {_{16}P_3} = 23,610$. I want to learn how to get the right answer without using the complement and find out what is wrong in my logic above.

Comment: Your count for 1 female officer should also include the number of ways to pick *which* office is held by a female officer. A similar adjustment needs to be made for the count for 2 female officers.

Comment: (Another way of putting this is: currently, your count for 1 female officer counts the number of ways to have a female president and the other officers male, but doesn't include situations like a female treasurer and the other officers male.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- To i): 
  There are $3$ such possibilities: 
  [image]
  $1$ female may be in the role of president, vice president, or treasurer.

---

- To ii):
  There are $3$ such possibilities: 
  [image]
  $2$ females may be in the roles of president and vice president, or president and treasurer, or vice president and treasurer.

---

- To iii):
  It's OK, there is only one such possibility:[image]

---

So your expressions both in i) and in ii) multiply by $3$, and you will obtain the right answer.

Answer (score 1):

There are three basic cases, all officers are female, two officers are female, and one officer is female.

When all are female the number of possibilities is $15\times14\times13=2730$.
When two are female the number of possibilities is $15\times14\times16\times3=10080$.
When one officer is female the number of possibilities is $15\times16\times15\times3=10800$.
Sum to get $23610$.

Answer (score 1):

> The way I tried to do this problem is that there are three cases:
>
> - i) If one officer is female: $15 \cdot {^{16}\mathrm P_2}$

Which officer?  You want to count ways to select one female officer, one position for her, and select and arrange two male officers. $${^{15}\mathrm P_1}\cdot 3\cdot{^{16}\mathrm P_2}$$

> - ii) If two officers are female: ${^{15}\mathrm P_2} \cdot {^{16}\mathrm P_1}$

Second verse, same as the first; this time selecting a position for the lone male  $${^{15}\mathrm P_2} \cdot {^{16}\mathrm P_1}\cdot 3$$

> - iii) If three officers are female: ${^{15}\mathrm P_3}$

... and that is okay.

> Then I add the three cases $15 \cdot {^{16}\mathrm P_2} + {^{15}\mathrm P_2} \cdot {^{16}\mathrm P_1} + {^{15}\mathrm P_3} = 9,690$ but the answer is wrong because when I use the complement I get ${^{31}\mathrm P_3} - {^{16}\mathrm P_3} = 23,610$. I want to learn how to get the right answer without using the complement and find out what is wrong in my logic above.

And lo, behold that: ${^{15}\mathrm P_1}\cdot 3\cdot{^{16}\mathrm P_2}+{^{15}\mathrm P_2}\cdot{^{16}\mathrm P_1}\cdot 3+{^{15}\mathrm P_3}=23,610$